# Reduktion von Personalpronomen zu Flexionsmorphemen

Tags: colloquial, morphology

Ist in der Germanistik die Ansicht verbreitet, dass sich in der gesprochenen Sprache eine alternative Flexion zur direkten Ansprache bspw. aus den Personalpronomen *du* und *Sie* entwickelt [hat] oder wird das generell als ein rein lautliches Phänomen (Verschmelzung, Verschleifung, Verkürzung) angesehen?

1. - *Weißte waste/wasse bist? Lügen tuste, dat biste!*
   - *Weißt du, was du bist? Lügen tust du, das bist du!*
2. - *Komm[en]se rein, könn[en]se rausgucken!*
   - *Kommen Sie [bitte] herein, [dann] können Sie hinausgucken!*

Comment: Nebenbemerkung: Lügen tun mit Lügner sein, passt irgendwie nicht zusammen, habe ich auch noch nicht gehört. Besser "Lügner biste, dat biste!

Comment: @Thomas kommt nicht aus NRW.

Answer (score 4):

Darüber hatte ich schon öfter nachgedacht, aber ich bin schon lange nicht mehr auf dem aktuellen Forschungsstand. Das Phänomen zieht sich in meiner Dialekt-Region durch die gesamte Konjugation: *habbich, hasse, hatter, hattse, hattet, hammwer, happter, hammse*; ähnlich *binnich, bisse, isser ..., kommich, kommße, kommter* ...; schön auch mit *'kriegen': krijjich, krichße, krichter, krichtse, krichtet, kringwer, krichter, kringse* - usw. Die Frage ist im Zusammenhang mit betonten und unbetonten Pronomen zu sehen - diese Unterscheidung scheint es etwa im Bairischen praktisch durchgängig zu geben (Ludwig Merkle, Bairische Grammatik, S. 122 ff.). In meiner Region (Ruhrgebiet) wird da zumindest in der 3. Person unterschieden: *dat hatt**er** immer abgestritten* (unbetont) vs. ***der*** hattdat immmer abgestritten (normal betont). Ein *er* wie in der Hochsprache würde hier ziemlich gekünstelt wirken, aber in den Grammatiken wird so ein *der* immer als Demonstrativpronomen und nicht als betontes Subjektpronomen der 3. Person aus der normalen Personalpronomen-Reihe gehandelt.

Das wär' mal ein schönes Forschungsprojekt.

Comment: Ach was Forschungsprojekt! Gleich eine Grammatik des Verschleifdeutschen! Ich freue mich sehr auf die Konjugationstabellen! Machmer Schluss mit der veralteten Schriftsprache! Schreimer die Verben wiemerse sprechen! Nehmwer ne zeitgemäße Morphologie!

Comment: Gemach, wir sprachen hier nur von Gesprochenem, kein Grund für derlei Aufgeregtheiten.